# Assistance with FOR /F loops

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have 350~ folders with 19,000~ files between them and need to do a little `cmd` wizardry with your help.

I have got a batch to run which will add the filename to the end of the file after --- which is always on line 5.

The issue I am having is that it will only run on files within the folder I point it to and not the subdirectories recursively.

I cannot find a workaround for allowing `/f` and `/r` to run at the same time and `forfiles` seems to not like tokens. `Dir /s` gives me wrong syntax when slotted in anywhere near `DIR`.

**The Code**

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

cd ./Data/*
for /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('DIR /b /a-d "*.*"') DO (
type %%a >>"Temp.txt"
echo %%a>>Temp.txt
del %%a
ren "Temp.txt" "%%a"
)
pause
```

**The Files / Folders Example**

```
\Data\BatchFile.bat  
\Data\file.txt (will change)  
\Data\1\file.txt (won't change)  
\Data\2\file.txt (won't change)  
etc
```

Any assistance would be appreciated. I am currently stuck and can't seem to find a way around this. I will keep you up to date with my progress.

Comment: You're working on **Windows** rather than **MS-DOS**, right??

Comment: Yes @aschipfl, Working on Windows and this has run and worked in my live environment thanks to Magoo. Test environment ran around 19,000 files and live ran at over 140,000 files and all worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would

```
cd .\Data
for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('DIR /s /b /a-d "*.*"') DO echo %%a>>"%%a"
```

do what you want to do (append the filename to the end of each file in the tree)

Note that `/` is a switch and '\' a directory separator. Sometimes you can use `/` in place of `\` but not always...

Also that `cd .\data` and `cd data` will do the same thing. `cd` changes the current directory ("logged" directory) to the destination. It makes no sense to add the `\*` part - you can only e logged into one directory at a time.

It's not clear what "line 5"  or "---" has to do with the matter. They're not addressed in the code you provide.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('DIR /s /b /a-d "*.*"') DO echo %%~nxa>>"%%a"
```

would append the filename+extension only (no path)

Comment: You are a god send, this works like a treat!

I modified the cd, good habit to get into, thanks. The line 5 and --- was an oversight in my part as my previous revision searched for --- on line 5 then placed it after that where as my newest one adds it to the end.

You have alleviated several hours of frustration.